# How would I insert one item into the user-edit page with templates?

Tags: theming, users

I'm looking to insert a button into the user edit page. I've seen examples of how to edit the entirety of the user-edit page, but I want to keep everything intact and only make one small change.

Is it possible to do this without building the entire user-edit page all over again from scratch?

Comment: do you want to edit the user form or the actual page (from the template)?

Comment: I want to insert a button that calls a function on click. I have it working as a custom block but would like to actually insert it into the form. If that's possible to do without editing the template that'd be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you could add a button into the template, this is done better with the forms api using a custom module. You can use [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) to alter the user_profile_form and only make the small change you want while leaving the rest of the form untouched.

As an example, you could add a button "My cool action" to the use profile form with the following code. You just need to replace MODULE with the actual name of the module you put it in.

```
function MODULE_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['actions']['newaction'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'My cool action'
    );
    $form['actions']['newaction']['#submit'][] = 'my_newaction_callback';
}

function my_newaction_callback($form, $form_state)
{
    // this function is called when your button is pressed
    // do whatever you want here.
}
```

**Update #2**

You could place the button in the middle or top of the page using the following code and figuring out which weight places it where you want. Try a weight of 0 to have it near the middle.

```
$form['newaction'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'My cool action',
    '#weight' => -3,
    '#submit' => ['my_newaction_callback']
);
```

Comment: Great it worked! Is it possible to place it somewhere in the middle of the user edit form?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how that's possible